# tweepy API.update_profile error tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I want to update my twitter profile name with bot. But it gave me 401.
here's my code

```
def main():
    
    auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
   CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESSS_TOKEN, ACCESSS_TOKEN_SECRET)

    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    api.update_profile(name="Henlo")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path-to-app/app.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "path-to-app/app.py", line 26, in main
    api.update_profile(name="Henlo")
  File "path-to-app/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "path-to-app/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 2752, in update_profile
    return self.request(
  File "path-to-app/venv/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 257, in request
    raise Unauthorized(resp)
tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Access token. It need write permission in order to make change to profile. Here's the detail [Generate Access Token with Read/Write Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71439161/how-to-generate-twitter-api-access-token-and-secret-with-read-write-permission)