# how to Generate Twitter API access token and secret with read/write permission

Tags: python, twitter, token, tweepy

I just created twitter api with elevated access but I can't generate access token with write permission. I need this permission to update my twitter name.
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

App settings -> User authentication Settings -> Edit.

Enable OAuth 1.0A ->

- App permissions Read and Write
- Callback URL can be set to something like `http://localhost` if you are not going to implement sign-in for other users
- Website URL set to something valid like your blog ideally, or use `http://example.com` if you must
  -> Save

App Keys & Tokens -> Authentication tokens
Regenerate Access Token and Secret

This will grant read and write permission to the app for the account that owns the app. It will not let any the app write to any other account.